# How to create a black curtain that only appears when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a black curtain on my site, but I want it to appear only when someone click in this button:

```
<a href="#dailyBriefOverlay" id="dailyBriefOverlay" class="pull-right btn-reservar">
    <span class="fa fa-ticket"></span>
</a>
```

I'm having trouble creating the effect that will cause it to appear only when clicked.

I created the div

```
    <div class="overlay" id="dailyBriefOverlay">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
```

and set the css:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    z-index: 99999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0 8%;
}
```

There is any jquery that help with that?

http://qz.com/ this site has this effect, if you click on the message icon, the window will appear.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Be more specific. Is the problem that it does *not* appear when you click, or is it that it appears *even* when you don't click?

Comment: ok, sorry..the window is appearing all the time, covering the site.

Comment: The mask always shows because you did not set it to not show

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any click events or any attempt to get something to change based on a click.

Comment: I don't see that window you refer

Comment: What you want is a Modal window:  http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: Use a modal, or set the properties of the overlay to `display:none;` and change it on a click.

Comment: Yeah, the last answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this task with pure CSS. Use [`:target`](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/) pseudo class for `.overlay` to show up only when it's targeted with URL hash.

For this you should hide `.overlay` initially and then use `.overlay:target` selector to show it. Also make sure you remove duplicated `id="dailyBriefOverlay"` from the link.

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    z-index: 99999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0 8%;
    display: none;   /* hide it */
}
.overlay:target {
    display: block;  /* show it if it's a target */
}
```

```html
<a href="#dailyBriefOverlay" class="pull-right btn-reservar">
    <span class="fa fa-ticket"></span>
    Click
</a>

<div class="overlay" id="dailyBriefOverlay">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

With this pure CSS approach it's also easy to add some nice CSS transitions. For example like in below demo.

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    z-index: 99999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0 8%;
    transition: height .4s ease;
}
.overlay:target {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#dailyBriefOverlay" class="pull-right btn-reservar">
    <span class="fa fa-ticket"></span>
    Click
</a>

<div class="overlay" id="dailyBriefOverlay">
    <p>test</p>
    <p><a href="#">Close</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i like your solution, but the window is showing up without my call

Comment: i dont know why, but now is working.. really great solution, genius i say.. @dfsq

Comment: there is any incompatibility issues with browser if i use the target pseudo class?? should i be  worried about that?

Comment: Browser [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=target) is pretty good: all modern browsers, IE9+.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it always shows right now.

Change your css to have the following line also:

```
display:none;
```

Now, use jQuery to show it when you click the button:

```
<script>
  $("#dailyBriefOverlay").click(function() {
       $(".overlay").show();
  });
</script>
```

It first checks on the id (dailyBriefOverlay) of the button if it gets clicked. When it does, it sets the display:none; property to display:block of the class (overlay)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn-reservar').on('click',function(){
    $('.overlay').animate({
       top: 10px, // or any value you want it to go to.
       display: block,
       atr: val// Any other value to change to.
}, 2000); // time in MS how long the animation lasts.
});
```

Think that'll do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#dailyBriefOverlay").hide();
    
    $("a#daailyBriefOverlay").click(function(){
        $("div#dailyBriefOverlay").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    z-index: 99999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0 8%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay" id="dailyBriefOverlay">
    <p>test</p>
</div>

<a href="#dailyBriefOverlay" id="daailyBriefOverlay" class="pull-right btn-reservar">
    <span class="fa fa-ticket"></span>
    Click Me
</a>
```

You should use JQuery to it. See running example!